# Weird nested flex HTML behavior

Tags: html, flexbox

Can't understand what's going on here, I'm getting some weird space under my text that grows proportionally with the text size.. Am I breaking some weird flex "law" here?

```css
.one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.three {
  width: 240px;
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
      <div>
        Chai tea sesame soba noodles strawberries pumpkin kimchi
        <!-- add more text here to make empty space grow -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with setting the `flex-wrap: wrap;` property. If you remove that, it'll work fine.

When you set the value to `wrap`, it forces elements to multi-lines, direction is defined by flex-direction

```css
.one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.three {
  width: 240px;
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
      <div>
        Chai tea sesame soba noodles strawberries pumpkin kimchi
        <!-- add more text here to make empty space grow -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Read about `flex-wrap` here - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/

Comment: I have just one element under that flex element, don't see how that should be affected by "flex-wrap".

Comment: But your `flex-wrap` is set at the top most element which has a `flex-direction: column;` so it tries to force it to a multi-line layout. If you remove it from the top-most parent and move your `flex-wrap` property to the immediate parent (`.two`) then it'll give you the desired output.

Comment: A distilled part of my answer has the "answer" to your question. When you say `flex-wrap: wrap;` you're telling the flex-items to be forced to multiple lines, it doesn't matter if there's 1 item or a hundred. And the axis for the wrap is directed by the `flex-direction` property. If you don't want to to be forced to mult-lines, then just use `flex-wrap: nowrap;` which is the default value for the `flex-wrap` property.